# In the Import/Export Wizard inside SSDT, why is the MSAccess DB Engine data source looking for a workgroup information file?

Tags: ssis, ms-access, ssdt

Running MSSQL12, VS10 Shell, MSA2013 with local .accdb files, Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable (x86_64) and Microsoft Access Database Engine 2007 Redistributable (x86) installed.

While trying to import to MSSQL2012 from SSDT using the wizard from an Access 2013 DB (.accdb) which is password protected, I get the following error with the username blank and the password field correctly populated:

```
Cannot start your application. The workgroup information file is missing or opened exclusively by another user. (MicrosoftOffice Access Database Engine)
```

But according to this link:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/what-happened-to-user-level-security-HA010342116.aspx

MSA10 and beyond shouldn't need workgroup information files, although it's not clear to me if they are created/used or not.

I can point the wizard to some local version of system.mdw at Advanced -> All -> Jet OLEDB:System Database, and then the error becomes:

```
Not a valid account name or password. (Microsoft Office Access Database Engine)
```

for any username I can think of.

I have discovered, serendipitously, that using the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard from the start menu (Import and Export Data (64-bit)), this problem goes away and the export proceeds normally.

That is, I select as data source "Microsoft Access (Microsoft Access Database Engine)", then my .accdb file.  In this case, it does not even ask for a password with the password field blank.  This suggests that it is not looking for a workgroup information file, as expected for a .accdb from MSA07 or later.

Also, I see that this problem is not limited to the wizard inside SSDT.  If I try to add a Connection Manager using the "Native OLE DB\MS 12.0 Access DB Engine OLE DB Provider", and then select my .accdb in "Server or File Name", when I "Test Connection" I get

```
Test connection failed because of an error in initializing provider. Unrecognized database format 'C:\myDB.accdb'.
```

Questions:

1. Why does this data source insist on looking for a workgroup information file even though user-level security should be disabled?
2. Why does the Open dialog box for the Microsoft Access Database Engine have *.mdb as the only selectable filetype?
3. How can I get around these errors for an .accdb that is password protected?
4. Why is SSDT behaving differently from MSSQL?  I need SSDT to work to use SSIS.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the SSIS project in 32- or 64-bit mode?

Comment: VS10 Shell seems to be a 32-bit app.  However, I see a flag in Project properties -> COnfiguration Properties -> Debugging -> Run64BitRuntime == True.

Comment: Also, I have noticed that by uninstalling the 64-bit 2010 redist and installing the 32bit version, this problem is solved.  But then I can no longer use the 64-bit Import/Export Wizard because it refuses to install both 32- and 64-bit 2010 redists.

Comment: Visual Studio is always 32-bit. If you have the 64-bit redist installed, does the SSIS package work if you execute it using the Execute Package utility?

Comment: @JonSeigel It's already uninstalled.  Executing the package with the utility works as expected.  I can live with 32-bit MSA drivers for what I'm doing, though I'm still unclear about what was happening here.